# Is the manga in Episode 3 of "The Everyday Tales of a Cat God" based off a real manga?

Tags: everyday-tales-of-cat-god

In episode 3 there is a manga about a girl who moves to Tokyo after a string of bad luck only to find that her roommate is a death god who seems to just mooch off her. I am wondering if this is based off of another manga.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can find more examples in [the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS4Gx.jpg) in the comments. I think that's a large enough sample to determine if the manga used in the anime is based off any other manga.

Comment: I uploaded some screencaps to [this imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/78zNJ). If anyone feels like picking out relevant-looking ones and editing them into the post, that'd be dandy.

Comment: The manga seems to be an original work of Yukina (by the duo responsible for the manga, FRIP FROPs). The details of the Yukina's manga in chapter 13 of the manga series are really shown so it's likely added in the anime to flesh things out a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[кяαzєя's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5370/is-the-manga-in-episode-3-of-the-everyday-tales-of-a-cat-god-based-off-a-real#comment7536_5370) is right on the spot: **Yes, it's from 大凶ちゃんとしあわせな世界** (*Daikyo-chan to Shiawase na Sekai*, Misfortune Girl and the Lucky World), a 2-chapter <s>special</s> spiritual one-shot by FLIPFLOPs on *Champion RED* magazine edition 2007-12 ~ 2008-01. It's also included in the 1st volume of *The Everyday Tales of Cat God* manga (Source:
[MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/10617/Nekogami_Yaoyorozu/moreinfo)).

> [image: cover page]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://blog.xuite.net/dk.miki/trans/21084422-%E5%A4%A7%E5%87%B6%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%82%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C)</sup>

The story, as it has been mentioned in the question, is about

> Kyouko, a test-taker who came to Tokyo and is living alone.
> Shinigami Karin, Kyouko's roommate.
> The story about their certain Sunday life.
>
> <sup>[Source (Japanese)](http://miruto.org/archives/1120.htm)</sup>

---

Here, we can see Shamo reading the *RED* magazine,

> [image: Shamo reading the RED magazine]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://nikkananilog.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-23.html)</sup>

And here is the scanned page of the last picture in the question,

> [image: "Let me pray for your own sake"]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://miruto.org/archives/1120.htm)</sup>